# Python - What is the fastest way to apply the same function to elements of a list

Tags: python, list

I have this list

```
l = ['2017-05-13 00:00:00', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-11 00:00:00']
```

and i want to remove for each element the `00:00:00` part. `elm = elm.split(" ")[0]`.

Is there a faster way to do this than

```
for elm in l:
    elm = elm.split(" ")[0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest method is using `list comprehension`, below are some cases :

Case 0 :

```
l = ['2017-05-13 00:00:00', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-11 00:00:00']
start0 = time.time()
output = []
for data in l:
    data = data.split(" ")[0]
    output.append(data)
print(output)
print(time.time()-start0)
['2017-05-13', '2017-05-12', '2017-05-11']
5.602836608886719e-05
```

Case 1 : With `lambda` and `map()` :

```
l = ['2017-05-13 00:00:00', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-11 00:00:00']
start1 = time.time()
print(list(map(lambda x:x.split(" ")[0],l)))
print(time.time()-start1)
['2017-05-13', '2017-05-12', '2017-05-11']
3.504753112792969e-05
```

Case 2 : `list comprehension`

```
l = ['2017-05-13 00:00:00', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-11 00:00:00']
start2 = time.time()
print([i.split()[0] for i in l])
print(time.time()-start2)
['2017-05-13', '2017-05-12', '2017-05-11']
0.00010156631469726562
```

Comment: Thanks very relevant

Answer (score 1):

When your datatime strings have a fixed size, you could slice the strings directly:

```
>>> l = ['2017-05-13 00:00:00', '2017-05-12 00:00:00', '2017-05-11 00:00:00']
>>> [i[:10] for i in l]
['2017-05-13', '2017-05-12', '2017-05-11']
```